# Grandfather opening the ark

Tags: pregnancy-birth, opening-the-ark

What is the origin of a grandfather opening the ark if his daughter is pregnant? I am familiar with the custom for the husband to receive this honor in Shul.

Comment: never heard of either custom - care ot provide a source?

Comment: There is a custom brought down in the name of the Rashba to open the aron for anin zemiros

Comment: I've heard that the reason the husband of a pregnant woman gets Pesicha is because it's a Segulah for an easy childbirth (something like: the Aron being opened symbolizes the womb 'opening' to let the child come out easily). Now, I'm no expert in how Segulah transfers work, but I don't see why the same reason wouldn't apply to the father of the pregnant woman too.